# toolbar in all views (global toolbar)

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

how can i define a toolbar which is available in all nibs?

i have 4 button in my toolbar. one of them is for first view(nib1)and 3 of them are for second view(nib2).

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better to create two identical toolbars and have the controllers for the two views forward the actions to each other. It all depends quite a bit on how you have structured your views and their controllers. Without that info it's hard to give your more detailed advice.